# Dynamic robots.txt based on hostname

Tags: nginx, robots.txt

Is there a way to swap out a robots.txt file in nginx based on hostname? I currently have www.domain.com and backup.domain.com pointing at the same nginx server, but I don't want Google indexing backup.domain.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. An `if` statement based on `$http_host` that rewrites to one of two text files on the backend.
2. Have robots.txt be rewritten to a dynamic script (robots.php etc.) that responds accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a proper way with [map](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html)

```
map $http_host $examplecom_robotstxt {
  hostnames;
  default robotstxt/development.txt;
  example.com robotstxt/production.txt;
}

server {
  ...
  location = /robots.txt {
    rewrite .* /$examplecom_robotstxt break;
  }
  ...
}
```

Please note that map definition should be outside of server definition.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this is the syntax I used:

```
if ($http_host != "www.domain.com") {
    rewrite ^/robots.txt /robots-backup.txt last;
}
```

This was inside the location block

Comment: `if` in `location` is evil. don't use it. never.

Comment: Can you suggest a better solution?

Comment: two `server {}` sections, of course. it's right way, recommended by nginx author.